# Returning count w/ data in MongoDB Aggregation

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, pipe, aggregation-framework

I've written a MongoDB aggregation query that uses a number of stages. At the end, I'd like the query to return my data in the following format:

```
{
    data: // Array of the matching documents here
    count: // The total count of all the documents, including those that are skipped and limited.
}
```

I'm going to use the skip and limit features to eventually pare down the results. However, I'd like to know the count of the number of documents returned **before** I skip and limit them. Presumably, the pipeline stage would have to occur somewhere after the `$match` stage but before the `$skip` and `$limit` stages.

Here's the query I've currently written (it's in an express.js route, which is why I'm using so many variables:

```
const { 
    minDate, 
    maxDate,
    filter,  // Text to search
    filterTarget, // Row to search for text
    sortBy, // Row to sort by
    sortOrder, // 1 or -1
    skip, // rowsPerPage * pageNumber
    rowsPerPage, // Limit value
} = req.query;



db[source].aggregate([
        {
            $match: { 
                date: {
                    $gt: minDate, // Filter out by time frame...
                    $lt: maxDate
                }
            }
        },
        {
            $match: { 
                [filterTarget]: searchTerm // Match search query....
            }
        },
        {
            $sort: {
                [sortBy]: sortOrder // Sort by date...
            }
        },
        {
            $skip: skip // Skip the first X number of doucuments...
        },
        {
            $limit: rowsPerPage
        },
]);
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Adding all the documents into an array might exceed the MongoDB single document limit i.e. 16MB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use [facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) to run parallel pipelines on the data and then merge the output of each pipeline.

**The following is the updated query:**

```
db[source].aggregate([
    {
        $match: { 
            date: {
                $gt: minDate, // Filter out by time frame...
                $lt: maxDate
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $match: { 
            [filterTarget]: searchTerm // Match search query....
        }
    },
    {
        $set: {
            [filterTarget]: { $toLower: `$${filterTarget}` } // Necessary to ensure that sort works properly...
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: {
            [sortBy]: sortOrder // Sort by date...
        }
    },
    {
        $facet:{
            "data":[
                {
                    $skip: skip
                },  
                {
                    $limit:rowsPerPage
                }
            ],
            "info":[
                {
                    $count:"count"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        $project:{
            "_id":0,
            "data":1,
            "count":{
                $let:{
                    "vars":{
                        "elem":{
                            $arrayElemAt:["$info",0]
                        }
                    },
                    "in":{
                        $trunc:"$$elem.count"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
]).pretty()
```

Comment: This is helpful, but I'm not sure how to apply it to my code. Could you please explain  how to apply $match and $sort to this example, so that they pertain to my request? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. But **if someone knows that this answer is slow, or at least faulty in some way, please let me know!**

It's to add a `$group` stage, passing `null` as the value, then pushing each document, `$$ROOT`, into the data array, and for each one, incrementing count by 1 with the `$sum` operator.

Then, in the next `$project` stage, I simply remove the `_id` property, and slice down the array.

```
db[source].aggregate([
        {
            $match: { 
                date: {
                    $gt: minDate, // Filter out by time frame...
                    $lt: maxDate
                }
            }
        },
        {
            $match: { 
                [filterTarget]: searchTerm // Match search query....
            }
        },
        {
            $set: {
                [filterTarget]: { $toLower: `$${filterTarget}` } // Necessary to ensure that sort works properly...
            }
        },
        {
            $sort: {
                [sortBy]: sortOrder // Sort by date...
            }
        },
        {
            $group: { 
                _id: null,
                data: { $push: "$$ROOT" }, // Push each document into the data array.
                count: { $sum: 1 }
            }
        },
        {
            $project: {
                _id: 0,
                count: 1,
                data: { 
                    $slice: ["$data", skip, rowsPerPage]
                },

            }
        }
]).pretty()
```